# How to consume Private Package Feed in Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure-devops, nuget

I have a private package on Azure DevOps which I consume by an API project.

For that I have in this API project the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <clear />
    <add key="nuget" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" />
    <add key="mypack" value="https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/org/_packaging/mypack/nuget/v3/index.json" />
  </packageSources>
  <packageSourceCredentials>
    <mypack>
      <add key="Username" value="EmailUserInDevOps" />
      <add key="ClearTextPassword" value="TokenFromDevOps" />
    </mypack>
  </packageSourceCredentials>
</configuration>
```

It works fine on my development machine ...

But I also want to build the API project using DevOps.

For that I connect DevOps to a Github repository where the API project is.

But in this repository I do not have the Nuget.config file.

I don't have it there to not expose my Password to mypack feed.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a NuGet restore step to your build and point it to the artifacts feed.

```
- task: NuGetCommand@2
  displayName: 'NuGet restore'
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    restoreSolution: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/WhateverProject.sln'
    feedsToUse: 'select'
    vstsFeed: 'feed guid'
    includeNuGetOrg: true
```

Additional authentication should not be necessary, as it's running in the context of a service that is already authenticated to your artifacts feed.

Comment: I already have such a step but my azure-pipelines.yml is on the GitHub repository. So credentials I put there are exposed in the Github repository.

Comment: @MiguelMoura You don't need to put credentials. I've updated my answer.

Comment: What you mean with Feed Guid in vstsFeed? I tried to use the Feed name and also the feed url and none of them worked.

Comment: @MiguelMoura I mean exactly what I said: The feed's GUID. It's a unique identifier, not a URL or a name. The easiest way I've found to get it is to use the visual designer and click the "View YAML" button, or use the REST API to retrieve the feed information.

Comment: Just to update, `vstsFeed` should be feed name instead of the feed guid now. I think this is a relatively recent update on Azure DevOps.